# Unity Multiplayer globally (World Wide)

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

i have developed a complete Airstrike Multiplayer game in unity using **Unity Multiplayer** Services. 
It's connecting successfully on **LAN** and i even checked on internet, it's working fine within my city using Matchmaking services.

Now, the problem is when i try to connect the game **between two different countries**, it does not show anything.

1. How can i run the multiplayer part globally using Unity Matchmaking Services ?
2. Is there something that needs to be changed here ? (This is my Network lobby manager):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unet-matchmaking-europe-north-america-cannot-see-rooms.345065/

As per the answer in the link above:

> Hi!
>
> We have 3 data centers right now, with plans for more going forward.
>   When you use the default URL, you'll connect to the most local data
>   center to you geographically. This is to minimize latency in
>   multiplayer games.
>
> In this case you're connecting to EU and your coworker is connecting
>   to US. Data centers are siloed from each other with respect to match
>   enumeration, so you wouldnt see each other's games.
>
> You can force a connection however directly to the data center of your
>   choice. Here's the list of current URLs to do so:
>
> EU: eu1-mm.unet.unity3d.com US: us1-mm.unet.unity3d.com AP:
>   ap1-mm.unet.unity3d.com

So it would appear that using this solution you would need to force a certain server for it to work globally, for example the European one, or somehow connect them differently.

There might be another solution, but at least this should work for testing.